# SQL - Updating table with informaton from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run an update on my companies eshop, but I'm racking my brain trying to work out the correct SQL command to do the following:

I have three tables:

```
Products
------------
pId
pSearchParams


ProductCategories
------------------
pcProductId      // products.pId
pcCategoryId     // categories.catId


Categories
----------
catId
catName
```

I need to update the `pSearchParams` field in the `products` table with the information from the `catName` field in the `categories` table.

The only way I can do this is to link the `products` table to the `productcategories` table, as the `productcategories` table is the only way I can establish a link between the `products` table and the `categories` table.

The problem is that in the `productcategories` table, `pcProductId` is likely to contain the same information on multiple rows, the same goes for `pcCategoryId` (e.g. products can be in multiple categories)

I need to run an `UPDATE` statement to update all the `pSearchParams` fields in the `products` table with the relevant category names, allowing for multiple category names.

If I need to provide more information please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Firebird?

Comment: Please edit your question, showing sample data and the results you would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE products AS p
JOIN productcategories AS pc ON (p.pId = pc.pcProductId)
JOIN categories AS c ON (pc.pcCategoryId = c.catId)
SET p.pSearchParams = c.catName
```

Update

```
UPDATE products AS p
SET p.pSearchParams = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.catName SEPARATOR ' ')
    FROM productcategories AS pc
    JOIN categories AS c ON (pc.pcCategoryId = c.catId)
    WHERE pc.pcProductId = p.pId
    GROUP BY pc.pcProductId
)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! Only issue is that it doesn't update it with multiple category names, just the first category name found.

Comment: You have one product in many categories and you want to concat all categories in one files?

Comment: Yes, most products are in multiple categories, so I will need it to update pSearchParams with every category name it is related to, seperated by a comma.